# How to enable VT-x from linux command line

Tags: virtualbox, intel, virtualization

Is there a way to enable VT-x from linux (not Windows) command line without having to reboot and enter the BIOS? Would be very useful since I don't have access to the server to enter the BIOS GUI.

Comment: If Vt-d is disabled in the BIOS, it is locked off and cannot be enabled without a reboot. However, if you want to change the setting from Linux and then reboot, it might be possible (if you’re using UEFI). It depends on whether the setting is in an EFI variable that can be written at runtime. I don’t know where that setting is stored or how to find it, but I’d start by looking at the Tiano source.

Answer (score 0):

Both on Windows and Linux you can manage the VMs from the command line using **VBoxManage** tool as long as the Vt-d is enabled in the BIOS. I'm not clear on why the nested-VTX function in the VirtualBox VM parameter appears "uncheckable" or unavailable anyhow. I've found this command very handy for the case:

VBoxManage modifyvm [name_of_vm] --nested-hw-virt on